# SSIS skip bad row

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

I have a file expecting 8 chars per line that I want to load to a table in SQL Server

```
ABCD1234
ABCD5678
!
DCBA4321
DCBA9876
>
ABCDEFGH
```

However I may get bad rows. With SSIS I tried all the 3 methods:
Determined with {CL}{RF}, fixed width and finally Ragged Right.
In all cases parsing fails and is redirected to the error table. When I remove the bad lines, everything is fine.

What is strange is that with a small sample like this it still works and is inserted to the expected table.
When file is big, parsing may fail not at the first bad row but second or third and insert all the rest in the ERROR Table.

Isn't it supposed to skip the bad row and insert the good ones in the expected table even when they come after?
Or is there another solution?

Comment: You say it's erroring, but you haven't included the error you're getting.

Comment: Erroring in SSIS redirects the insertion of the row to the error table with a random number error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a conditional split component with the following expression in order to ignore bad rows:

```
LEN([InputColumn]) == 8
```

I think this will work as expected.

- [SSIS Basics: Using the Conditional Split](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-conditional-split/)